# How to use queryOrderedByValue on 2 levels deep children?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch some game stats from my DB, and i have a structure like this one:

[image: firebase database structure]

and I'm struggling to obtain the desired "percent" child sorted by values.

My code is:

```
func compareTheResult(key: String) {
let refDb = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("game-stats").child(key).queryOrderedByValue().queryLimited(toLast: 5)

refDb.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        print("here the snapshot of compare the result", snapshot)
        }, withCancel: nil)}
```

and I only know the key. I've tried with `queryEqual` and `queryOrderedByKey` and some other methods, but I can't get it to work the way I want.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the 5 highest ranked players by percentage in key game.

```
let refDb = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("game-stats").child(key).queryOrdered(byChild: "percent").queryLimited(toLast: 5)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was just trying to come up with this for like a one and a half hours.